# Setting context variable

Tags: flutter, dart

Many of my functions use context inside, because they use snackbar. I keep them in a separated file.

Is it a good idea to create variable BuildContext currentContext and override it in every screen? Those functions would be much more readable without passing context argument every time to each one, they would use currenntContext instead

Answer (score 0):

### Is it a good idea to create variable BuildContext currentContext and override it in every screen?

#### NO

If it is possible to do this, then what do you think happens if you or someone on your team forgets to set the variable once? worst case scenario the app crashes, but I believe it will just lose functionality

Having global variables in general is not a good idea because it leads to difficult to track code, because running the same function with the same parameters will not necessarily yield the same result.

The above is doubly true for context, because the one reason you have access to context is so you pass it to the functions you are using so they can figure out how your widget tree looks.

basically, ***it's bad practice***, which I know doesn't mean a lot, but there is a reason why good practices are good practices and bad practices are bad practices.

### Is it *possible* tho?

After a bit of testing, I came to the conclusion that it **IS** possible to do what you seek.

The only thing you have to keep an eye out for is that the value of your global context contains a scaffold, it sounds obvious, but it's easy to forget:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ContextProvider.globalContext = context;

  return Scaffold(...);
}
```

The code above will not work, because at the time of assigning context, there was no scaffold on the widget tree, it will also not work if you assign global context on `initState`, you will have to do something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Builder(builder: (context) {
      ContextProvider.globalContext = context;
      return ...
    }),
  );
}
```

or something of the sort.

I haven't tested setting global context using the context from a stateful widget, which has access to it's updated context everywhere, so maybe it is worth trying that to save yourself from the builder hell you are about to get yourself into?